# How to know cropping dimensions for an <img> that has been translated and scaled?

Tags: python, html, css, image

I have a web page that is constructed using high-res images but not all of each image is visible. I need to optimize the size of the entire page so I'd like a way to know what the final, visible dimensions are so I can crop each image. Each image is displayed using something like this:

```
<div class="picClipper">
    <img class="pic" style="transform: scale(1.17) translate(10px, 0px);" src="pic1.jpg">
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.picClipper { height: 50%; overflow: hidden; }
.pic { height: 100% }
```

What I'd like to end up with for each image is the visible pixel x,y,w,h so I can then crop each JPG (and save with lower quality but not sure that's relevant). The translate part seems like simple math but I'm not sure how to calculate how the scale factor affects the numbers. Is there a way to calculate this by simple analysis of the HTML/CSS or do I need to use JavaScript after things are rendered? The first is much preferred but either is workable.

If it matters, I'm using Python 3 so I'd prefer doing this in Pillow but I'm happy to do other things like shell out to something like ImageMagick. I'll use Beautiful Soup to find the img elements and extract the transform attributes. Also, this is not running in production or at scale: this is on my desktop in Firefox or Chrome so slow speed and non-elegant solutions are probably ok.

It just needs to be automatable: the desired end result is me pointing some code at an HTML file and a set of images and the output is new HTML that is pointing at a set of optimized images. Unless a complete tool already exists for this, I assume I'll write the code - I just need a way to accurately determine the cropping coordinates.

Comment: Give your img `object-fit: cover` & provide it its cropping height & the width. Then use `object-position` to specify the x & y origin of the cropping. Should work